# node, express, mongoose don't work together

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hej people

I try to create some fullstack app (base on one tutorial) and I have some problem with understand how backed part work. Teoreticlly, then I did this tutorial first time, everything was working. But now, then I try to something new base on it, I see how many things I don't understand. Basically, why it won't work.

I generate express app. My app.js looks that:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/covid', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
}).then(() =>  console.log('connection successful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var casesRouter = require('./routes/cases');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/api', casesRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

routers/cases.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var Cases = require('../models/Cases.js');

server.listen(4000)

// socket io
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('newdata', function (data) {
        io.emit('new-data', { data: data });
    });
    socket.on('updatedata', function (data) {
      io.emit('update-data', { data: data });
    });
});

// list data
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Cases.find(function (err, cases) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(cases);
    });
})

module.exports = router;
```

and schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CasesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  name: String,
  location: String,
  state: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cases', CasesSchema);
```

ok, it's all.

So now I run it from my console by nodemon. In console everything looks ok. No error, and message that everything is ok. But app is not working:

1) I expect that this part:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/covid', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
}).then(() =>  console.log('connection successful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

should created me now new schema "covid" with object Cases with keys id, name, location, state. It didn't happen. I installed Compass to easiest examination my mongodb and I can see, that I don't have something like covid. ok, I created it manually, But, as I understand, it should be done automaticlly after I run nodemon.

2) I expect that I can examination my backend via postman. https://localhost:3000/api/ (3000 - nodemon default port), but I

> Could not get any response There was an error connecting to
>   https://localhost:3000/api/.

and it's everything. I can't see this error neither in console nor postman.

Maybe I don't understand something with ports in express app, or I don't understand something with mongoDB. But google didn't help me. It did only bigger mess in my head. So maybe someone of you can explain me how it should work and why?

Comment: Can you please add port behind mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/covid'')

Comment: I tried it. Nothing changed.

Comment: Try it with https://localhost:4000/api/.

Comment: I understand at mongoose.connect? Nothing new, unfortunately.

Comment: According to compass my mongo is at port 27107. And, as I understand at port 4000 should be my frontend.

Comment: check whether the collection is created or not from mongo shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209436/discussion-between-juhil-somaiya-and-tomh).